# java hashtable with composite key

Tags: hashtable, composite-key

Given the java codes below:

```
public static Hashtable<String[],Integer> testTable = new Hashtable<String[],Integer>();

public static String [] compositeKey = {"key1","key2","key3"};
public static String [] testKey = {"key1","key2","key3"};
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    if (!testTable.containsKey(compositeKey)){
        testTable.put(compositeKey,1);
    }


    if(testTable.containsKey(testKey)){
        System.out.println("got!");
    }
    System.out.println(testTable.get(testKey));
}
```

The output from console is:

```
null
```

It uses a String array as a key, and the 'testKey''s content is the same as 'compositeKey'. Why the output is null? Originally I am thinking the output should be:

```
got!
1
```

And what should I do if I want to use a composite key like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that String[] equals uses the default Object.equals implementation and only compares object identities.

What you'll need to do is make your String arrays into List objects that properly implement equals for an array of things.

Try this instead:

```
public class Test {
    public static Hashtable<List<String>, Integer> testTable = new Hashtable<List<String>, Integer>();

    public static String[] compositeKey = { "key1", "key2", "key3" };
    public static String[] testKey = { "key1", "key2", "key3" };

    public static List<String> compositeKeyList = Arrays.asList(compositeKey);
    public static List<String> testKeyList = Arrays.asList(testKey);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (!testTable.containsKey(compositeKeyList)) {
            testTable.put(compositeKeyList, 1);
        }

        if (testTable.containsKey(testKeyList)) {
            System.out.println("got!");
        }

        System.out.println(testTable.get(testKeyList));
    }
}
```

Comment: very good! these extra tests confirmed it to me, thx vm! `if (testTable.containsKey(Arrays.asList(testKey))) { System.out.println("got too!"); }; if (testTable.containsKey(Arrays.asList(new String[]{ "key1", "key2", "key3" }))) { System.out.println("got three!"); };`

Answer (score 0):

Your two arrays are different objects, so they are not equal, even when their contents are equal.